# How to dump remote mysql database and import it locally using bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, function, ssh, remote-server

Trying to dump a remote wordpress database using that shell script:

```
db_name=$(php -r 'include("public_html/local-config.php");echo DB_NAME;');
db_user=$(php -r 'include("public_html/local-config.php");echo DB_USER;');
db_password=$(php -r 'include("public_html/local-config.php");echo DB_PASSWORD;');
db_host=$(php -r 'include("public_html/local-config.php");echo DB_HOST;');
mysqldump --user="$db_user" --password="$db_password" "$db_name";
```

To have the dump locally I run this in my local terminal (host in .ssh/config):

```
ssh host 'bash -s' < thatscript.sh > dump.sql
```

Then I would do `mysql localdb < dump.sql` to import it locally.

Now I tried to put the ssh and local mysql part into the script as well, so that I can just fire up the script and it does everything.

I tried to put the original script into a function and then call it using

```
mysql localdb < $(ssh host 'bash -s' < myDumpFunction)
```

but that assumes a file called myDumpFunction and obviously does not work. How would I call the function in that case correctly?

Any other ideas on how to achieve a one line database sync for a local dev system are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

What about writing another .sh file and starting it with ssh connection ? Do not forget to change chmod. Script should be executable.

example:

```
ssh username@ipaddr(remotePc) start.sh
```

Comment: I did consider that but then I have two scripts hanging around to do one job. That did not seem very elegant to me, thats why I wondered how to do it in one script.

Comment: So you can use upstart function. But I always use such solutions, because it is useful and practical while working ssh connection or remotely.

Comment: @mcnesium if this solution works, click as solved for other users

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, but as I already stated, your answer is not really suitable for my problem, sorry.